# Mac crashing randomly for the admin user. Works fine when using as a guest user. Any help appreciated

Tags: shutdown

Here is the error log

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffff0193768d0): "i2c0::_checkBusStatus SCL is stuck low; last write status 00010108 int shadow 00010100 xfer 00000000 fifo 00000000 for device audio-tas5770L-spkr-woofer-l" @AppleS5L8940XI2C.cpp:430
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 19P5071
macOS version: 21F79
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 21.5.0: Tue Apr 26 20:35:13 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.121.3~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
Kernel UUID: 015E49E0-D2AC-3BFD-9465-D0AAA435B13E
iBoot version: iBoot-7459.121.2
secure boot?: YES
x86 EFI Boot State: 0x16
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0xec
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x70707060400
PCIeUp link state: 0x1611
Paniclog version: 13
Kernel slide:      0x0000000011038000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffff01803c000
mach_absolute_time: 0x1189c062b
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x62adb342 0x0002f8bc
  Sleep   : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Wake    : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Calendar: 0x62adb402 0x0004d315

Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xffffffe017270000 - 0xffffffe617270000
  . VM    : 0xffffffe017270000 - 0xffffffe0fd8d4000
  . RO    : 0xffffffe0fd8d4000 - 0xffffffe14a5a0000
  . GEN0  : 0xffffffe14a5a0000 - 0xffffffe230c04000
  . GEN1  : 0xffffffe230c04000 - 0xffffffe317268000
  . GEN2  : 0xffffffe317268000 - 0xffffffe3fd8d0000
  . GEN3  : 0xffffffe3fd8d0000 - 0xffffffe4e3f38000
  . DATA  : 0xffffffe4e3f38000 - 0xffffffe617270000
  Metadata: 0xffffffe00c668000 - 0xffffffe00de68000
  Bitmaps : 0xffffffe00de68000 - 0xffffffe00e0cc000

CORE 0 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 1: PC=0xfffffff01887a4a0, LR=0xfffffff01887a4a0, FP=0xffffffe617613f00
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Panicked task 0xffffffe31691cc50: 657 pages, 10 threads: pid 47: bridgeaudiod
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe31698a2d8, backtrace: 0xffffffe617682b60, tid: 1318
          lr: 0xfffffff01884a504  fp: 0xffffffe617682ba0
          lr: 0xfffffff01884a28c  fp: 0xffffffe617682c10
          lr: 0xfffffff018982a40  fp: 0xffffffe617682c80
          lr: 0xfffffff018981aa4  fp: 0xffffffe617682d30
          lr: 0xfffffff018ea55fc  fp: 0xffffffe617682d40
          lr: 0xfffffff018849fa8  fp: 0xffffffe6176830d0
          lr: 0xfffffff018849fa8  fp: 0xffffffe617683130
          lr: 0xfffffff0199cb2e4  fp: 0xffffffe617683150
          lr: 0xfffffff0193768d0  fp: 0xffffffe6176831f0
          lr: 0xfffffff019376a28  fp: 0xffffffe617683210
          lr: 0xfffffff01937642c  fp: 0xffffffe617683260
          lr: 0xfffffff018f397dc  fp: 0xffffffe617683280
          lr: 0xfffffff018f39644  fp: 0xffffffe6176832b0
          lr: 0xfffffff018df0798  fp: 0xffffffe617683320
          lr: 0xfffffff018f3a04c  fp: 0xffffffe617683380
          lr: 0xfffffff0192feef8  fp: 0xffffffe617683400
          lr: 0xfffffff0192fec98  fp: 0xffffffe617683490
          lr: 0xfffffff0192ffed0  fp: 0xffffffe6176834c0
          lr: 0xfffffff01998ffb0  fp: 0xffffffe6176834f0
          lr: 0xfffffff0199902d8  fp: 0xffffffe617683510
          lr: 0xfffffff019316f80  fp: 0xffffffe617683540
          lr: 0xfffffff018df0798  fp: 0xffffffe6176835b0
          lr: 0xfffffff0192f0f40  fp: 0xffffffe617683660
          lr: 0xfffffff0192f6420  fp: 0xffffffe617683710
          lr: 0xfffffff0192f603c  fp: 0xffffffe617683750
          lr: 0xfffffff0192f5d48  fp: 0xffffffe6176837b0
          lr: 0xfffffff018dee448  fp: 0xffffffe617683800
          lr: 0xfffffff019324ab0  fp: 0xffffffe617683860
          lr: 0xfffffff018df0798  fp: 0xffffffe6176838d0
          lr: 0xfffffff019324858  fp: 0xffffffe617683950
          lr: 0xfffffff018e2b038  fp: 0xffffffe617683af0
          lr: 0xfffffff018949d68  fp: 0xffffffe617683c10
          lr: 0xfffffff018850718  fp: 0xffffffe617683ca0
          lr: 0xfffffff0188236d4  fp: 0xffffffe617683d00
          lr: 0xfffffff01883a44c  fp: 0xffffffe617683d90
          lr: 0xfffffff018976ff8  fp: 0xffffffe617683e60
          lr: 0xfffffff018981f3c  fp: 0xffffffe617683f10
          lr: 0xfffffff018ea55fc  fp: 0xffffffe617683f20
```

Comment: It's something in the audio - have you got any 3rd party audio plugins/fx/routers?

Comment: That the computer operates correctly with a guest user, but fails with the admin user, suggests that there's something different about the setup for the admin user, or that the admin user runs some software (as @Tetsujin suggests) that's fouling things up. Use [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) to diagnose what's going on.